# regex item count

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have two distinct styles of item count text to extract the total number of items from.

From style 1 I need the number 3, From Style 2 i need 56

```
Style 1:
3 Item(s)

Style 2:
Items 1 to 45 of 56 total
```

I was trying this to match

```
/(?<page>\d+,?\d+) total| Item\(s\)/
```

It matches the 56 in style 2 but not the 3 in style 1.

This will be used with preg_match in php ( we can't change that as we are feeding values via a webform )

I have some other regex's I've tried, which I could post if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `total`, `item` inside a capturing or non-capturing group, so that the first pattern would become a common one for both `total` and `Item`.

```
(?<page>\d+(?:,\d+)*)(?: total| Item\(s\))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vQ4tX9/2)

Comment: Excellent thank you, I'd tried to upvote but it won't let me :(